# Titanium Android Option dialog reset

Tags: android, titanium

I'm stuck on a problem with the option dialog whenever I use it for the second time the option I selected from the first time is still highlighted and I can't seem to undo this. Does anyone know a solution for this problem?

i summon the optiondialog by a tableview click event

```
var option = Ti.UI.createOptionDialog({
    title: 'Verander Status',
    options:['Afgerond','Bezig','NVT','Cancel'],
    cancel:3
});
option.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    var naam = t1;
    var db = Ti.Database.open('Opleiding');
    if( e.index == 0){ 
        db.execute('UPDATE ICTVAKKEN SET status ="A" WHERE Name =? ',naam);
    }
    if(e.index == 1){
        db.execute('UPDATE ICTVAKKEN SET status ="B" WHERE Name =? ',naam);
        }
    if(e.index == 2){
        db.execute('UPDATE ICTVAKKEN SET status ="N" WHERE Name =? ',naam);
    }
    Gettable();
    db.close();

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no option to reset the option dialog. But you can try the following code that creates a optionDialog each time when you want to display the option dialog.

```
var options = {
    title: 'Verander Status',
    options:['Afgerond','Bezig','NVT','Cancel'],
    cancel:3
};

var button = Ti.UI.createButton({
    title : 'Show Dialog',
    color : '#000'
});

win.add(button);


button.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    Ti.UI.createOptionDialog(options).show();
});
```

This will do the trick.

Comment: Sorry for the late reaction,
it kinda works but do you have a solution to use a eventlistener for this way?

Comment: @Rick: I guess no. The above code recreates the option dialog so that the options will reset. Whenever we keep the same instance of the option dialog, the options will keep selected.